# How to change word order from within a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that returns from my Backend: startDate: "September 28, 2021" in the format: mm-dd-yyyy.
I need to format this string in Front to display: yyyy-mm-dd ie: 2021, September 28.

How do I format a string and change the order of the words contained in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement here:

```js
var input = "September 28, 2021";
var output = input.replace(/\b(\w+ \d{1,2}), (\d{4})\b/, "$2, $1");
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

Regarding the choice of regex pattern I used, it should be sufficient and safe assuming that nothing else in your text would be a word followed by a 1-2 digit number, comma, then a 4 digit number.

Comment: The regex worked, but I have a question, in the case of Chinese characters (月) will it work?

Comment: I'm doing a test with the following sentence: 9月 28, 2021

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easy one that will also validate your date too

```
let date = new Date("September 28, 2021");
let month = date.toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" });

let fomattedDate = `${date.getFullYear()}, ${month} ${date.getDate()}`;

console.log(fomattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

RegEx works, but if you want to be able to read and understand the code:

```js
const input = 'September 28, 2021';
const [month, day, year] = input.split(' ');
const formattedDate = `${year}, ${month} ${day.replace(',', '')}`
```